# Can my Android app detect if it was launched from Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there a way for an Android activity to detect how it was launched?  Specifically, I would like to detect if my app was started from Eclipse, versus if it was started normally (e.g., from the home screen or installed application list).

This is a proxy for knowing if crash reports should be uploaded or not.  I'm assuming if Eclipse launched the app, then I don't need to uploaded crashes, because I'm already debugging  the app, but if the same build of the app is started "normally", I'd like to upload any exceptions.

This is just to make my personal debugging and development easier, so unshippable hacks or tweaks to Eclipse are useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#isDebuggerConnected%28%29) method appears to do what you require:

```
if(!android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected()) {
    // Send report...
}
```

This should tell you if you're currently attached to a debugger. If launched from the app drawer or a homescreen shortcut, you won't be attached (unless you already have a running instance that *is* attached) and this method will return false - in this case you can upload your crash information.

Comment: This will check if the app is actually being debugged.

Comment: Yes, which is one of at least two distinct ways it can be launched from eclipse.

Comment: I just tried this and get true when run from the Eclipse Debugger (and false when run from the launcher).  Running the app "normally" from Eclipse also returns false, though.  Running under the debugger is a little heavyweight, for every usage but maybe I can get used to that.

Comment: Perhaps I misread the question - "if Eclipse launched the app, then ... I'm already debugging the app." I read this as a desire to not-upload when you've got the debugger attached (and hence can break into the code to see state and so on). Of course, if you want to not-upload when launching with the Run option, this answer doesn't really help!

Comment: This returns always FALSE for me, even when I run it from Eclipse in Debug Mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
`if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)`
 to tell a debug build from a release build.

Comment: This is also useful, but you need to be careful with it - it appears you can sometimes get a release build with BuildConfig.DEBUG set to true. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27940) and [here](http://www.digipom.com/be-careful-with-buildconfig-debug/).

Comment: As understand, that is a property of a build (its a constant in the app).  I'd like to test something that changes depending on how the (debug-build) app is started.

Answer (score 1):

You (I?) can add a new activity to the app, and have Eclipse launch that. The new activity will set a flag that otherwise doesn't get set, and otherwise be the same.  Regular use of the app will come through the default activity, and so the flag will be defaulted to unset.

Add a new `DebugActivity` that extends existing activity (call it `MainActivity`):

```
public class DebugActivity extends MainActivity {
    public DebugActivity() {
        super(true); // running from Eclipse
    }
}
```

Add a new boolean constructor and no-arg constructor to `MainActivity` to support the new subclass:

```
private final boolean viaEclipse;

public MainActivity() {
    this(false);
}

public MainActivity(boolean viaEclipse) {
    this.viaEclipse = viaEclipse;
}
```

Duplicate the `<activity>` information in the app manifest for `.MainActivity`, but change the duplicate to reference the new `.DebugActivity`.  Remove the `<category>` tag (the "LAUNCHER" one) from the `.DebugActivity` `<intent-filter>` to prevent it from showing up in the Android UI.

In Eclipse, choose `Run -> Run Configurations ...`. Select the existing run configuration for the app.  Click the icon that "Duplicates the currently selected Launch Configuration", and on the `Android` tab in the duplicate change the `Launch Action` from "Launch Default Activity" to "Launch: " and select the new `.DebugActivity`.

**Downsides**

1. Eclipse "debug" runs are not identical to a "real" run, but the difference is pretty small (basically just the launch class name and an extra entry on the stack).  There is no duplicated code on the Java side, at least.
2. I duplicated most of the content of my `<activity>` in the manifest, which is a little fragile but not too bad.

Still would be nice to have something simpler than this.

Comment: If you remove the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` line from your DebugActivity entry in your manifest, it won't appear as an icon in your launcher :)